# Python3 and hmac . How to handle string not being binary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encoding, hmac

I had a script in Python2 that was working great.

```
def _generate_signature(data):
   return hmac.new('key', data, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Where data was the output of `json.dumps`.

Now, if I try to run the same kind of code in Python 3, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/hmac.py", line 144, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/hmac.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" %type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

If I try something like transforming the key to bytes like so:

```
bytes('key')
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

I'm still struggling to understand the encodings in Python 3.

Comment: I get this for that. `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use bytes literal: `b'key'`

```
def _generate_signature(data):
    return hmac.new(b'key', data, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

In addition to that, make sure `data` is also bytes. For example, if it is read from file, you need to use `binary` mode (`rb`) when opening the file.

Comment: how can I use bytes literal for a param?

Comment: By prefixing `b` in front of string literal.  `'key'`: string, `b'key'`: bytes.

Comment: I still get some error like this : `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: @Tessaracter, Are you using Python 2.x? Then encode the data, `hmac.new(b'key', data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()` (Change `utf-8` accordingly)

Comment: @falsetru . Nope I am using python 3.6

Comment: @Tessaracter, please post a separate question with code that reproduce your issue.

Comment: @falsetru . I am banned from asking questions. Not really sure what to be done. (Have read in meta that I have to wait for 6 months)

Comment: @falsetru May be I'll ask on github issues and post the link here soon

Answer (score 42):

Not to resurrect an old question but I did want to add something I feel is missing from this answer, to which I had trouble finding an appropriate explanation/example of anywhere else:

Aquiles Carattino was pretty close with his attempt at converting the string to bytes, but was missing the second argument, the encoding of the string to be converted to bytes.

If someone would like to convert a string to bytes through some other means than static assignment (such as reading from a config file or a DB), the following should work:

(Python 3+ only, not compatible with Python 2)

```
import hmac, hashlib

def _generate_signature(data):
  key = 'key' # Defined as a simple string.
  key_bytes= bytes(key , 'latin-1') # Commonly 'latin-1' or 'ascii'
  data_bytes = bytes(data, 'latin-1') # Assumes `data` is also an ascii string.
  return hmac.new(key_bytes, data_bytes , hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(
  _generate_signature('this is my string of data')
)
```

Comment: Note that this solution will not work if the code is in a python 2.7 package but being called from python 3. This is because in python 2 the `bytes` builtin is simply an alias for `str`. I was able to write a function that works from either python 2 or 3 by coercing the strings into bytearrays which are valid in both versions of the language.

Comment: ^ true dat, python3 only.

Comment: the answer is good but it is has many unnecessary details that is not exact and precise: for Latin characters bytes(key , 'latin-1') === bytes(key , 'ascii') === key.encode('ascii') but
for unicode support we need bytes(key , 'utf-8') === key.encode('utf-8').

Answer (score 9):

try

> codecs.encode()

which can be used both in python2.7.12 and 3.5.2

```
import hashlib
import codecs
import hmac

a = "aaaaaaa"
b = "bbbbbbb"
hmac.new(codecs.encode(a), msg=codecs.encode(b), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Work Mar 2021. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for python3 this is how i solved it.

```
import codecs
import hmac

def _generate_signature(data):
  return hmac.new(codecs.encode(key), codecs.encode(data), codecs.encode(hashlib.sha256)).hexdigest()
```