# Google OAuth in Python 3 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, base-conversion

I followed [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549884/5078779) for implementing Google OAuth in Python. However, when I tried running in Python 3, I get this error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

This error is thrown by this line:

```
o = ord(h[19]) & 15
```

Trying `o = ord(str(h[19])) & 15` resulted in:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

This happens in Python 3, but not in Python 2, which makes me think that some types have changed between versions. This is the relevant code:

```
def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = ord(h[19]) & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h
```

I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31848293/7214321)'s answers, but they did not help. The first answer did not help because I am not using a string literal for `key` or `msg`. This was my attempt at implementing the second answer's suggestion:

```
def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret)
    key_bytes = bytes(key, 'latin-1')

    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    msg_bytes = bytes(msg, 'latin-1')

    h = hmac.new(key_bytes, msg_bytes, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = ord(h[19]) & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h
```

This code threw this error on the `key_bytes = <...>` and `msg_bytes = <...>`:

```
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Using `utf-8` instead of `latin-1` had the same result.

If I `print(key, msg)`, I get this, which suggests that they are already in a byte-like form:

```
b'fooooooo37' b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xfa\x93\x1e'
```

The `msg` printed explains the `... string of length 3 found` error above.

---

I am unsure where to go from here. Any suggestions/solutions would be great!

Comment: can you print value of `h[19]` and `type(h[19])` ?

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan, `print(h[19], type(h[19])) => 112 <class 'int'>`. The `112` changes to a different number on different runs though (as it should).

Comment: `ord()` expects a character of length 1, that is the same in Python 2 and 3. It  returns an integer representing Unicode code point for the given Unicode character.

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan, yes, but it is getting an integer, not a character from `h[19]`

Comment: Try using h[19] without `ord()`

Comment: @RakeshAdhikesavan, ah phd *just* beat you to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hmac.new()` returns a string of bytes. In Python 3 this is an array of integers. Hence `h[19]` is an integer. Just use that int instead of calling `ord()`. Or decode `h` to str.